# Downloading data from Adwords and using Pandas to read the file

Tags: python, pandas, google-ads-api

I am using Python to download some reports from Adwords and then pandas to reformat the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from googleads import adwords

    stream_data = downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
        products_query,
        'CSV', output_file,
        client_customer_id='xxxxx',
        skip_report_header=True,
        skip_report_summary=True,
        skip_column_header=False)

    data = pd.read_csv(output_file,
                       sep=',',
                       encoding='utf-8-sig',
                       header=1,
                       error_bad_lines=False,
                       warn_bad_lines=False)
    print(data)
```

The file that is produced looks like this:

```
647972293,695588-4,enabled,enabled,1,0.00,2017-04-01,2,50.00%,0.00%,0.00,350000,0.00
647972293,794745-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,5,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
647972293,695882-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,1,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
647972293,798115-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,6,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
647972293,649265-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,4,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
647972293,265195-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,17,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
647972293,115024-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,3,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
647972293,660673-4,enabled,enabled,0,0.00,2017-04-01,1,0.00%,0.00%,0.00,0,0.00
```

However, I am getting this error for some reason:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nasiantalla/PycharmProjects/adwords_test.py", line 95, in <module>
    error_bad_lines=False)
  File "/Users/nasiantalla/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/nasiantalla/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Users/nasiantalla/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/nasiantalla/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/nasiantalla/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 535, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:6086)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 710, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas/parser.c:8843)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11308)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 2014, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:26862)
TypeError: raise: exception class must be a subclass of BaseException
```

I tried with some different eroding types, but still the same.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6035

and try casting the separator as a string?

```
sep = str(‘,’)
```